# How to use a functions returned value as a condition?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, return

I'm trying to make a start_game button for something I am working on but I don't understand how to use the return value of a function. Here's my example.

```
start_game = ttk.Button(frame, text="Start Game", command=startgame)
start_game.grid(column=1, row=2)

def startgame():
    return True

if startgame() is True:
    """Run the game"""
```

I know this is wrong and I have spent some time looking for an explanation but all I seem to find is how to print the return value of the function.

Comment: Why do you think that's wrong? `if startgame():` would work just fine. If you're trying to launch from your `command`, just wrap the game code up into a function rather than an `if` block.

Comment: Because when I run it, it is just assuming start_game() is true before I even press the button and the whole game is starting. I thought about putting it into a function but I really am just trying to understand how to return something from a function and then use that as a condition, because I still don't have a good understanding of how that works

Comment: Nonsense. My advice: stay away from GUI apps for a while. Understand the core language first.

Comment: @Doc_Apes of course it is, **that's what `startgame` returns**. I second the above comment, see http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Comment: Ok  I think I get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will need to be this, you don't need the "Is True"

```
start_game = ttk.Button(frame, text="Start Game", command=startgame)
start_game.grid(column=1, row=2)

def startgame():
    return True

if startgame():
    """Run the game"""
```

But it seems that startgame is already true, so you could just write out your code or define it as a function such as

```
def game():
   """Game Code"""
```

Then you can call the function by using

```
game()
```

Comment: This is **no different**. `True is True`, that's not the problem here. Also it would be helpful if you'd highlighted the change and/or explained how it (doesn't) help.

Comment: I tried that but it is just starting the game before I press the button...

Comment: @Doc_Apes I thought that you were having trouble with the condition

Comment: Thanks for the help I realise I am going about this the whole wrong way but cheers!

Answer (score 0):

since [`command`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Button.html) runs a function, just put your game code into that function:

```
start_game = ttk.Button(frame, text="Start Game", command=rungame)
start_game.grid(column=1, row=2)

def rungame():
    """Run the game"""
```

---

in your original code, the code `startgame()` executed the function `startgame` which returned `True` regardless of any other code.

the pattern you might have been aiming for would require cooperative co-routines, event loop, multi-threading or other form of concurrency which is too complicated topic for now, but simplified pseudo-code algorithm would look like this:

```
start_game = ttk.Button(frame, text="Start Game", command=allow_game)
start_game.grid(column=1, row=2)

game_allowed = False
def allow_game()
    global game_allowed
    game_allowed = True


while True:
    if game_allowed:
        """Run the game"""
        break
    else:
        """run an infinite loop waiting for game_allowed to be True,
           but you must run it in a way that allows ttk to execute the 
           allow_game(), not this simple while loop
        """
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice I think thats what I am going to do and just go off and do some more study of my own and try and get my head around functions better.

Comment: I added some pseudo code to explain a pattern you were probably trying to implement, but it would need to be even more complicated to actually work